# Does the order of parameter types change the signature of a method in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, overloading, signature

*For the following methods: Does the order of parameter types result in unique method signatures?*

```
static void PrintOrderCost(double totalCost, string customerName)
{

}
```

Above Method Signature: **PrintOrderCost(double, string)**

```
static void PrintOrderCost(string customerName, double totalCost)
{

}
```

Above Method Signature: **PrintOrderCost(string, double)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specified in the [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#signatures-and-overloading):

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, the number of type parameters and the type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal parameters, **considered in the order left to right**. [...]

So yes, the order is part of the signature, so a different order is a different signature. The two methods shown are two overloads, because:

> Overloading of methods permits a class, struct, or interface to declare multiple methods with the **same name**, provided their signatures are unique within that class, struct, or interface.